# Trouble trapping 2501 error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am sending data from frmSearchEmployeeWorksheets to frmStatsCorr which runs a query (qryStatsCorr). On frmStatsCorr I am checking to make sure the query returns records otherwise I will Msg the user and return to the search form. My problem is that I am having problems 'ignoring' the 2501 caused by the **DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmStatsCorr")** which I learned here on Stackoverflow...

What am I doing wrong that is causing me major Access VBA Frustration??

This is the sub on the Search form (frmSearchEmployeeWorksheets):

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
    ' I only change focus to force the updated data to submit to query
    Me.[txtEmployee].SetFocus
    Me.txtShift.SetFocus

If txtUnit = "7" Then
    'First close the form in order to update
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmStatsCorr"
    ' Open Stats form
    On Error GoTo myErr
    **DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmStatsCorr") 'causes error** 
End If

myExit:
    Exit Sub

myErr:
    Echo True
    If Err.Number = 2501 Then GoTo myExit
        MsgBox Err.Description
    GoTo myExit

End Sub
```

In frmStatsCorr I simply check to make sure the query returns records if not I inform the user, close the form, and return to the frmSearchEmployeeWorksheets

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If strFormStatus = "view" Then

    If DCount("*", "qryStatsCorr") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Your search does not produce any results. Try a different search.", vbOKOnly
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmSearchEmployeeWorksheets")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    txtDay = WeekdayName(Weekday(Me.WorkDate)) 'This line returns an error so I check for an empty query and return to the search form.
    Me.[WorkDate].SetFocus
    Me.txtUnit.Enabled = False...
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I am having problems 'ignoring' the 2501`? What happens? Any error messages?

Comment: Also, what is the `Echo True` command in the error handler `myErr`? Is it one of your subs or functions? Otherwise that could be one of your problems.

Comment: Thanks for helping... I just removed the Echo statement but even with the On Error statement I keep getting the Run-time error 2501.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure how well I understand your code or the logic behind it.  My hunch is you should check the `DCount` result from `btnSearch_Click`, and not fiddle with closing then re-opening `frmStatsCorr`, and having `frmStatsCorr` close itself when it contains no data.  Just do not open `frmStatsCorr` when it will not contain data.

If the current form (`frmSearchEmployeeWorksheets`) which holds your `btnSearch_Click` procedure contains unsaved data changes, you can save them with `Me.Dirty = False`

```vb
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
    Dim strPrompt As String

    If Me.Dirty Then ' unsaved data changes
        Me.Dirty = False ' save them
    End If

    If Me.txtUnit = "7" Then
        If DCount("*", "qryStatsCorr") = 0 Then
            strPrompt = "Your search does not produce any results. " & _
                "Try a different search."
            MsgBox strPrompt, vbOKOnly
        Else
            ' if frmStatsCorr is open, just Requery
            ' else open frmStatsCorr
            If CurrentProject.AllForms("frmStatsCorr").IsLoaded Then
                Forms("frmStatsCorr").Requery
            Else
                DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStatsCorr"
            End If
            ' uncomment next line to close current form
            'DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If `frmStatsCorr` is open and you need to check whether it is in Design View, examine its `CurrentView` property.

```vb
Forms("frmStatsCorr").CurrentView ' Design View = 0
```

I suggested that approach because I suspected `frmStatsCorr`'s `Form_Load` may trigger the 2501 error when it closes itself.  But I'm not certain that's the cause of the error and I'm not motivated enough to set up a test.

If you still have 2501 errors with the approach I suggested, there are two other possible causes I've encountered:

1. corruption
2. broken references

Comment: 1. Checking on the btnSearch click just makes too much sense but OK I'll do it the easy way if you insist. ;)

2. The Me.Dirty solution will remove a whole bunch of Focus commands and cleans up my hack. Thanks for that too.

3. You rock. Get Yo HansUp, get yo HansUp, get yo HansUp... I'll give this a look right now.

Comment: OK. Checking for query results on click of the search button BEFORE opening the results from was the way to go. It is a lot cleaner and just plain obvious. I was stuck in the box. Thanks for that!

Comment: the Me.Dirty, although is a great solution for my other forms, will not work with unbound forms. This is a search form with a start date and end date so I don't know of any other way to 'commit' the entry other than shifting the focus around before submitting the data to the query. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, Bach!  I assumed a bound form.  Still, if you enter a value in an unbound text box, then click a command button, that click sets focus away from the text box (onto the button) so the text box's updated value should be available to the button's click event procedure ... without the need to do any explicit `.SetFocus` stuff.  BTW, I appreciate the cheerful spirit of your comments.  They gave me an early morning smile.  :-)

Comment: The clicking of a command button wasn't doing it. That is the only reason I began to 'hack' a way to get it to change. "Explicit" .SetFocus is a nice way of saying ridiculous workaround...so thanks for being polite. BTW: If we can get you an afternoon smile now then it will be the minimum I can do to repay your efforts.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, Rod man.  Use this as the first line in your button's click event procedure: `MsgBox Screen.ActiveControl.Name` If it replies with the name of anything other than your command button ... um, I'll be surprised.  Cheers.

Comment: Surprise! Unfortunately I'm getting "txtStartDate". Maybe that is only on bound forms? I keep reading that on unbound forms you are on your own in terms of tracking changes, etc.

Comment: Not on bound forms either.

Comment: Turns out `btnSearch` is an image control, *not* a command button.  That makes a world of difference.